# assign address to a iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

AS we know that iterators in cpp points to a certain element of a container like if we talk about vector

```
vector <int> v = {1,2,3,4,5}

vector<int>::iterator ptr;
ptr=v.begin();
```

Than ptr will point to first block of memory say 200
Let's declare another iterator

```
vector<int>::iterator ptrend;
ptrend=v.end() 

which point to just next follow of last element say will 
be equal to 220
```

My doubts

1)  And we know that `v.end()-v.begin() = v.size()`
    but which is not true in our case `220 -200 =20 != size`

2) Lets say `vector<int>::iterator ptr=v.begin();`
   here can we assign something like this `ptr = &a[3]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, there is one particular fault: You are asking two questions, which is generally bad.

Comment: But you still replied :p but I agree with your answer ;)

Comment: It seemed convenient, because both questions are more or less based on the same flawed assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check out the definition of "pointer arithmetic" in C++, which works in elements, not bytes. Then, just because an iterator references an object at a certain address doesn't mean that the difference between two iterators is the same numeric value as the difference between two addresses they reference.

Secondly, just as above, just because an iterator references a certain address doesn't mean that you can assign an address to that iterator. Think about what makes an iterator different from a pointer and combine that with your knowledge about encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

1) 20 bytes, yes, considering 4 bytes per elements, that's about right. But computing `v.end()-v.begin()` will give you the size for vectors (and more generally for random access iterators **only**), not the difference in their address. This is not pointer arithmetics with `char*`, it's `operator-` on iterators, which is implemented differently.

2) Iterators cannot be created out of pointers in general. But you can use `std::advance(std::begin(a), 3)` which may increment one by one or directly use `+3` depending on the iterator type.